# how to link to html on github

Tags: html, css, github, hyperlink

Ok so I know how to do this as I have other pages and the links work fine.

Though with this link it will just not work-

[Jessica Hische](http://mrzackrox.github.io/Jessica-Hische/jessica_hische_finial.html)

As you can see above this is the link in question. I have rechecked and rechecked it but it seems that it will not work.

Here is the link to my GitHub page were you can see what the other files are etc-
https://github.com/MrZackrox/Jessica-Hische

Any help would be great, I am just hoping its not a spelling mistake :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far I understand you want to run the HTML content of your github project. If that is the case you can use the `http://rawgit.com` domain.

For example:

```
http://rawgit.com/MrZackrox/Jessica-Hische/master/jessica-hische-essay.html
```

Comment: Yes thats what I want to do. I haven't done that on the other links and they work fine. It seems like the file is not there. I will try this and see if it fixes it. Thanks

Comment: That worked but the style is not working on it, time to fix that now lol.

Comment: Glad to hear it. If this answer help you somehow please accept it. Regards